# In Xcode how do I specify the correct library in my project settings to avoid a link error?

Tags: xcode, linker, undefined-symbol

I get a Undefined symbols error attempting to build an XCode project, and I'm pretty sure it is because the linker can't find a library (it's the library needed to use curses.h btw).  I'm writing a terminal program.  The errors I'm getting are:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _main in RogueSmackCmdLine.o
  "_wrefresh", referenced from:
      _main in RogueSmackCmdLine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and the offending lines of code are:

```
WINDOW *win = initscr ();
wrefresh(win);
```

This oughta be easy for some of you guys. Help finding the right place in the Project Settings and knowing what to put there wd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linking Libraries in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like those are from ncurses. You should right-click on your Frameworks folder in Xcode's file browser, select Add->Existing Frameworks…, and select libncurses (or libcurses) from the list.

Comment: That did it all right. Muchas gracias. And now I have a runtime error.  (sigh) It'd be nice if things would occasionally just work.