# Linking Libraries in Xcode 3

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I have only used Xcode 3 for self-contained programs. This time though I have to use a Big Number library. I've downloaded gmp and tried to link it with Xcode 3. To be honest I mostly have no clue what I'm doing. Can you guys explain thoroughly how to link a Big Number library like gmp so I can use it to calculate huge numbers?

Edit: I am working in C++ and I need to be able to do any mathematical operation, like addition, square root, exponent and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to incorporate that code depending on depended use and desired platforms.  But this seems like a pretty solid starting point.

https://github.com/bmorton/GMPInt

If this is not want you want can you tell us what language and platform you are working with?

Comment: Good point, I'm working in C++ and I want to be able to do any mathematical operation on the number. i.e addition, square root, exponent and so forth. I'll add that to the description

Comment: you don't have to link the lib. the c source is included in the release. you can still use the dynlib or you can create a .a and link to it. more on linking a .a here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode

Comment: Just to be sure I get that right, gmp is included in Xcode 3 using C++? Or some big number library is included in Xcode 3 (using C++)? So then in that case I could just include the headers I want, right?

Comment: GMP provides C code (how it's written.) You can just add that code to your project and call it directly.

Comment: The thing is there are a lot of files to include, there are 37 .c files not counting the ones in folders. Do you know of any implementation like your github link but for C++?