# Linking Error in Xcode and gtk

Tags: xcode, linker, linker-errors, gtk3

I am trying to build an interface with glade using C language and Xcode. I installed the library add added it to **"other linker flags"** in Xcode. I guess I am not linking it properly in the IDE. I get the following error:

```
"ld: library not found for -lgobject-introspection
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

How to properly link libraries in Xcode?

Comment: Did you add the gobject libraries to your project?

Comment: Use GtkBuilder, instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available in another post [Linking Libraries in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode)
The idea is to properly link the library in the **linker flags** like this:

`-lgobject-introspection`

then to add the path of the library in the **Search header paths** in Xcode.
This way, you tell Xcode to search the specified library in the added path.