# Boost Serialization example Error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

When I try to build/run a `boost-Serialization` example-code program, I'm getting errors, which I can't resolve and the code is from the boost serialization tutorial, so I don't think that it's wrong. I'm using the NetBeans 8.0.2 IDE and the Boost Library Version 1.58.0.
The code:

```
#include <fstream>

// include headers that implement a archive in simple text format
//#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
//#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include "../boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp"
#include "../boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// gps coordinate
//
// illustrates serialization for a simple type
//
class gps_position
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    // When the class Archive corresponds to an output archive, the
    // & operator is defined similar to <<.  Likewise, when the class Archive
    // is a type of input archive the & operator is defined similar to >>.
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
    }
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
public:
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {}
};

int main() {
    // create and open a character archive for output
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");

    // create class instance
    const gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f);

    // save data to archive
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa << g;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    // ... some time later restore the class instance to its orginal state
    gps_position newg;
    {
        // create and open an archive for input
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        // read class state from archive
        ia >> newg;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And now the error messages:

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/boost_serialization build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_register(std::type_info const&)", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position>::extended_type_info_typeid() in main.o
  "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_unregister()", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position>::~extended_type_info_typeid() in main.o
  "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::extended_type_info_typeid_0(char const*)", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position>::extended_type_info_typeid() in main.o
  "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::~extended_type_info_typeid_0()", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position>::~extended_type_info_typeid() in main.o
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position>::extended_type_info_typeid() in main.o
  "boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code, char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<float>(float&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<int>(int&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::save_impl<float>(float const&, mpl_::bool_<true>&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::save_impl<int>(int const&, mpl_::bool_<false>&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::tracking_type&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::class_id_type&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<boost::archive::object_id_type>(boost::archive::object_id_type&) in main.o
      ...
  "boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<float>(float&) in main.o
      void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<int>(int&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::save_impl<float>(float const&, mpl_::bool_<true>&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::save_impl<int>(int const&, mpl_::bool_<false>&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::tracking_type&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::load<boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::class_id_type&) in main.o
      ...
  "boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::load_override(boost::archive::class_name_type&, int)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_iarchive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::operator>><boost::archive::class_name_type>(boost::archive::class_name_type&) in main.o
  "boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::text_iarchive_impl(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_iarchive::text_iarchive(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int) in main.o
  "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
  "boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int) in main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::newtoken()", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<float>(float const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<int>(int const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::tracking_type const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>(boost::archive::class_id_reference_type const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::class_id_type const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::object_reference_type>(boost::archive::object_reference_type const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save<boost::archive::object_id_type>(boost::archive::object_id_type const&) in main.o
      ...
  "boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::~basic_text_iprimitive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::~text_iarchive_impl() in main.o
  "boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::~basic_text_oprimitive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~text_oarchive_impl() in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::load_object(void*, boost::archive::detail::basic_iserializer const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::detail::load_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::load_standard::invoke<gps_position>(boost::archive::text_iarchive&, gps_position const&) in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::~basic_iarchive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::text_iarchive>::~common_iarchive() in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_object(void const*, boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save_standard::invoke<gps_position>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, gps_position const&) in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::end_preamble()", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, float>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, float const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, int>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, int const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::tracking_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::tracking_type const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::class_id_reference_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::class_id_reference_type const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::class_id_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::class_id_type const&) in main.o
      void boost::archive::save_access::save_primitive<boost::archive::text_oarchive, boost::archive::object_reference_type>(boost::archive::text_oarchive&, boost::archive::object_reference_type const&) in main.o
      ...
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::~common_oarchive() in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_iserializer::basic_iserializer(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::detail::iserializer<boost::archive::text_iarchive, gps_position>::iserializer() in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_iserializer::~basic_iserializer()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::detail::iserializer<boost::archive::text_iarchive, gps_position>::~iserializer() in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer::basic_oserializer(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&)", referenced from:
      boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive, gps_position>::oserializer() in main.o
  "boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer::~basic_oserializer()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive, gps_position>::~oserializer() in main.o
  "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::is_less_than(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::serialization::detail::singleton_wrapper<boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position> > in main.o
      vtable for boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position> in main.o
  "boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::is_equal(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::serialization::detail::singleton_wrapper<boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position> > in main.o
      vtable for boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position> in main.o
  "boost::serialization::extended_type_info::key_register() const", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position>::extended_type_info_typeid() in main.o
  "boost::serialization::extended_type_info::key_unregister() const", referenced from:
      boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position>::~extended_type_info_typeid() in main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::serialization::extended_type_info_typeid<gps_position> in main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::archive::archive_exception", referenced from:
      void boost::serialization::throw_exception<boost::archive::archive_exception>(boost::archive::archive_exception const&) in main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_iarchive& boost::serialization::smart_cast_impl::reference<boost::archive::text_iarchive&>::polymorphic::cross::cast<boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive>(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&) in main.o
      typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<boost::archive::text_iarchive> in main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive", referenced from:
      boost::archive::text_oarchive& boost::serialization::smart_cast_impl::reference<boost::archive::text_oarchive&>::polymorphic::cross::cast<boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive>(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive&) in main.o
      typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive> in main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_iserializer", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::iserializer<boost::archive::text_iarchive, gps_position> in main.o
  "typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::oserializer<boost::archive::text_oarchive, gps_position> in main.o
  "vtable for boost::archive::archive_exception", referenced from:
      boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&) in main.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Not all Boost libraries are header-only, some have actual libraries that needs to be linked with.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link against `libboost_serialization`:

```
g++  main.cpp -lboost_serialization
```

Comment: How do I do that? In Project-Preferences -> Linker?

Comment: @user3653164 I have no Idead which IDE you use, if it is XCode, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode