# Undefined symbol _stdscr and _wgetch

Tags: c++, xcode, getch

When I add `getch()` to my two functions I got errors stating:

```
"Undefined symbol: _stdscr" and "Undefined symbol: _wgetch"
```

I am using a MacBook with the library `#include <curses.h>` in Xcode

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like [`getch()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) might not be a good idea. Try using C++ [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) instead. If you must use C, then [`getchar()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) will work on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-lcurses` option (link directive) while compiling.

For example : `clang++ main.cpp -o main -lcurses`

If you are using `make` then add `LDLIBS = -lcurses` to your `makefile`.

I just noticed that you are using XCode. So here you go : [Linking Libraries in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449087/11613622). Just replace `-lfftw3` in the answer by `-lcurses`.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to c++.

Comment: @JohnTasci I had mentioned a link, it has step by step procedure on how to do that. Have you tried going through that? If yes, can you be more specific about what problem are you encountering then?