# How to include an open source library into C++ project?

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I am trying to use an open-source library into my project, specifically this one [here](https://github.com/google/benchmark#usage).

I have followed the installation guidelines and installed it globally with

```
sudo cmake --build "build" --config Release --target install
```

And I could see that the library is installed in `/usr/local/lib`, now back to my own C++ code, when I tried to

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
```

as shown in the instruction still no go with error

```
'benchmark/benchmark.h' file not found
```

SO is there any step that is missing?

In `/usr/local/lib` I have:

```
libbenchmark.a
libbenchmark_main.a
```

And in `/usr/local/include` I have:

```
benchmark
```

I am not using CMake for my XCode project.

-------------- Segmentation ------------

After digging on the question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project)

I added this `/usr/local/include` into the `Header Search Paths` as following.

[image]

And then I tried

```
#include "benchmark/benchmark.h" // I tried <benchmark/benchmark.h> as well
```

But this resulted in a direct build failure with error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "benchmark::internal::InitializeStreams()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: I assume it put the headers in `/usr/local/include` and you don't have that path in your compilers include directories.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, inside the folder I have the folder `benmark`, how can I include it?

Comment: That would be some setting you need to change in XCode. I don't use that IDE so I can't tell you were the setting is.

Comment: Here is an old question on how to add the include path in XCode: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134064/how-to-set-include-path-in-xcode-project)

Comment: This question can probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445815/linking-libraries-in-xcode

Comment: I expect that @MJeremy was not using CMake for the xcode project but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am not using CMake

Comment: At least type what is actual problem? `still no go` is not explanation of error message! Can't find include file? Linking issue? [ask]

Comment: I don't think the proposed duplicate helps with the include path. I believe the problem is can't find the header.

Comment: @MarekR thanks for the prompt response, error msg is updated. I am actually clueless of the nature that's why I posted. BUT now as drescherjm suggested, I guess it would be the lib path is not included in the XCode?

Comment: After update it is clear that JoaoCostaIFG comment (voted up) is a correct solution.

Comment: Now you have to actually tell xcode to link to the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the many helps, I have finally figured it out.

Go to `build settings` in Xcode and add both header and library search path

[image]

And then go to `linking`, add linkers, for my case it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project uses `cmake` too, your `CMakeLists.txt` should contain something like this:

```
find_package(benchmark REQUIRED)

add_executable(YouLibBenchamrkTarget sources1.cpp ...)
target_link_libraries(YouLibBenchamrkTarget YourLibraryTarget benchmark::benchmark)
```

This should resolve problems with include and linking issues (you didn't specified actual nature of your problem).